# Assign Network Security Group to a Virtual Machine Network Interface using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I have existing NSG and VM and planning to add the NSG to existing VM's NIC and simultaneously remove as well. I have prepared this based on example provided in http://windowsitpro.com/azure/manage-network-security-groups-powershel. The below command failing with method not supported errors.

```
$NICName = 'azwebvm0186'
$RGName = 'Prod_ResourceGroup'
$NsgName = 'Prod_ILB_SG'

$NSG = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NsgName -ResourceGroupName $RGName
$NIC = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NICName -ResourceGroupName $RGname
$NIC.NetworkSecurityGroup = $NSG
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $NIC
```

its failing with below error

```
$NIC.NetworkSecurityGroup = $NSG : Specified method is not supported.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [], PSNotSupportedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in my lab, your script works for me. I think you had better check as the following ways:

1.Check `$NSG` and `$NIC.NetworkSecurityGroup` value and type. Please ensure they have the same type.

```
PS C:\Users\v-shshui> $NIC|gm


   TypeName: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSNetworkInterface
```

2. Check your Azure Powershell version. My version is 3.3.0. You could get version by use the following cmdlet.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

If your version is not latest, I suggest you could update your version to latest. You can download the PS version 3.3.0 installation file from this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v3.3.0-December2016)

Comment: Thank you, after upgrading Azure module to 3.3.0. it worked.